# Powershell compare two CSV files, how do you make it case-insensitive?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV files I am comparing, one has two columns, the second file has three.  I am needing the output of all three columns from the input from the first CSV file.

The code I am currently using is as follows

```
$ErrStatus = Import-Csv .\StatusErrorResults.csv

$StatLibrary = Import-Csv .\Status_Library.csv

Compare-Object $StatLibrary $ErrStatus -Property Device,Status -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | Select-Object \* -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation .\StatusErrorResultsFiltered.csv"
```

It is ignoring a section of the Status Library due to case sensitivity, how can I include regardless of case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Compare-Object` is case-insensitive by default, but you have `-CaseSensitive` switch to change that.